# Is there any R package to create the generalized box plot as mentioned in the research paper of (Bruffaerts, et al., 2014)

Tags: r, data-science, exploratory-data-analysis

I have a highly skewed and heavy tailed data. For this reason, instead of using the adjusted boxplot in R (which accounts only for the skewness of the data and not the underlying heaviness of the tail), I wanted to use the generalized boxplot since it accounts for both skewness and heaviness of the tail.

I am unable to try the generalized boxplot since I could not find its R package (if any).

https://sci-hub.hkvisa.net/10.1016/j.spl.2014.08.016

Comment: a link to the paper will be very useful

Comment: Yes sure.
Here it is: https://sci-hub.hkvisa.net/10.1016/j.spl.2014.08.016

Comment: They appear to have created a stata module, at least https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/GBOXPLOT%3A-Stata-module-to-create-Box-plot-for-or-Bruffaerts-Verardi/02081d216c727f9f836ebf310efcc441716d751f

Comment: So, @Phil it means that we do not have the R package for the generalized boxplot but instead it can only be done via STATA.

Comment: Following @Phil 's hint, I could find the stata code [here](http://fmwww.bc.edu/repec/bocode/r/robbox.ado) and the help file [here](http://fmwww.bc.edu/repec/bocode/r/robbox.sthlp). Unfortunately I don't know much of stata programming, nor I could find any R package to accomplish this. Perhaps porting this code to R could make for a wornderful learning project. If so, please share it in github or some other repo ;)